# remove the specific character in the string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

- I have one string

  ```
   var tStr="[[[{"Name":"A","No":"8000444284"}],{"Name":"B","No":"8485990983"}],{"Name":"C","No":"0000000000"}]";
  ```
- In this string i try to remove all `[` and `]`

My Code is:

```
function trim(str, characters) 
{
  var c_array = characters.split('');
  var result  = '';
  for (var i=0; i < characters.length; i++)
    result += '\\' + c_array[i];
  return str.replace(new RegExp('^[' + result + ']+|['+ result +']+$', 'g'), '');
}
```

And this Function Use as

```
trim(str,'[ ]');
```

In Calling `var tStr="[[[{"Name":"A","No":"8000444284"}],{"Name":"B","No":"8485990983"}],{"Name":"C","No":"0000000000"}]";`

thats not working please any one help me...:)

Comment: What is the problem with `replace`?

Comment: you can use .replace() method str.replace('[','');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\[|\]
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/4

```
var re = /\[|\]/g;
var str = '[[[{"Name":"A","No":"8000444284"}],{"Name":"B","No":"8485990983"}],{"Name":"C","No":"0000000000"}]';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Error Comes : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at the replace() function line

Comment: the actual purpose is i have dictionary and that i convert into string than after convert into the dictionary then push one array and than using `JSON` storing into local-storage.

Comment: @virbhadrasinhGohil should work.Check d demo.the code is working .There is problem somewhere else in ur code

Comment: ya ya you are right, your answer is perfect ,this string is into the dictionary without convert into string i'll do this,, thx